# SQL - Retrieve only one record of related records

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have table which depicts shares of a particular type of record. 2 records are created for a shared item which results in something like this

```
|--------------|------------|
|  Shared From | Shared To  |
|--------------|------------|
|   Record 1   |  Record 2  |
|--------------|------------|
|   Record 2   |  Record 1  |
|--------------|------------|
```

Is it possible to retrieve a single share record ? Meaning that from the table above I get only one record (Doesn't make a difference which)

```
|--------------|------------|
|  Shared From | Shared To  |
|--------------|------------|
|   Record 1   |  Record 2  |
```

Using distinct on both columns doesn't work since the combination is different

Comment: Specify the expected result.

Comment: @jarlh Included, thanks

Comment: Question, you work in batch and you table have more than 2 lines ? like you input in not true, you should have at least `3->4` and `4->3` ?

Comment: If you have only one row with a combination, does it matter if col1 and col2 are switched?

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` expressions to return the smaller value in the first column, and the larger value in the seceond column. Do `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

```
select distinct case when SharedFrom < SharedTo then SharedFrom else SharedTo end,
                case when SharedFrom > SharedTo then SharedFrom else SharedTo end
from tablename
```

**Note:** May switch columns for unique combinations. (If col1 > col2.)

Comment: Care to explain the behaviour of `> / <` with string ?

Comment: @Blag . . . I'm baffled.  Why does that need explaining?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get a single line from the table. 
To get the top N of rows in a table, you can use `TOP('N')`, for example:

```
SELECT TOP(1) share_column FROM shares_table
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Thank for you response, but I think this don't answer the question (you probably have more than 2 line in the input)